# Can't create dependency property in a UserControl in a Windows Runtime Component library

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I wanted to created data bindable property inside a user control. And this user control contains inside a **"Windows Runtime Component"** project. I used below code to create property.

```
public MyItem CurrentItem
{
    get { return (MyItem)GetValue(CurrentItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CurrentItemProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CurrentItem. 
// This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentItem", typeof(MyItem), typeof(CollapseUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

When I compile the project I get below error.

```
Type 'HierachyLib.CollapseUserControl' contains externally visible field 'HierachyLib.CollapseUserControl.CurrentItemProperty'.  Fields can be exposed only by structures.
```

**Update 1 - Source code for whole class**

```
public sealed partial class CollapseUserControl : UserControl, IHierarchyHeightFix
{
    public MyItem CurrentItem
    {
        get { return (MyItem)GetValue(CurrentItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentItemProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CurrentItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentItem", typeof(MyItem), typeof(CollapseUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    Boolean viewState = true;

    public CollapseUserControl()
    {
        this.DataContext = CurrentItem;
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += CollapseUserControl_Loaded;
    }

    void CollapseUserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData();
        if (this.Height.Equals(double.NaN))
        {
            this.Height = 50;
        }
        //this.Height = 50;
        //this.Width = double.NaN;
    }

    private void LoadData()
    {
        if (CurrentItem != null)
        {
            if (CurrentItem.IsValueControl)
            {
                ChildItemContainer.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
                ValueItem.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;

                ValueItem.Text = CurrentItem.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                ChildItemContainer.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
                ValueItem.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;

                ChildItems.ItemsSource = CurrentItem.Childs;
                //foreach (MyItem item in CurrentItem.Childs)
                //{
                //    CollapseUserControl control = new CollapseUserControl();
                //    control.CurrentItem = item;
                //    ChildItems.Items.Add(control);
                //}
                ChildItems.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (viewState)
        {
            ChildItems.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
            //show.Begin();
        }
        else
        {
            //hide.Begin();
            ChildItems.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        viewState = !viewState;
    }

    private void hide_Completed_1(object sender, object e)
    {
        ChildItems.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private void show_Completed_1(object sender, object e)
    {
    }
}
```

**Update 2 : XAML Code**

```
<UserControl
x:Class="HierachyLib.CollapseUserControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:HierachyLib"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">
<UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ReviewsItemsTemplate">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,20">
            <TextBlock Text="TEST" />
            <TextBlock Text="TEST"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ReviewsItemsPanelTemplate">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="Auto"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<!--xmlns:my="clr-namespace:HierarchyCollapse"-->
<Grid>
    <Grid Name="ChildItemContainer">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,70,0" Fill="Transparent" Canvas.ZIndex="4"/>
        <ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FF6599CD" CanDragItems="False" CanReorderItems="False" Grid.Row="0"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" 
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="40">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Text="Sample Text" FontSize="17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,10,0,0" Canvas.ZIndex="10"/>
                                        <Image PointerPressed="Button_Click_1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="Assets/arrw_right.png" Stretch="None" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListViewItem />
        </ListView>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1"
            IsHitTestVisible="True"
            CanDragItems="True" 
            CanReorderItems="True" 
            AllowDrop="True" 
            Name="ChildItems" 
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsItemClickEnabled="False">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:CollapseUserControl CurrentItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
    <TextBlock Name="ValueItem" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="40" FontSize="36"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

New error I get:

```
Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Xaml.PropertyPath' from the text ''.
```

Error comes from `<local:CollapseUserControl CurrentItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />`.

Comment: Can you show the whole code of your class?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Question is updated with source code of the class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like you can mark your property as internal and then it starts working...

```
internal static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentItemProperty...
```

EDIT*

A better approach that seems to be what the platform controls do is to have an actual CLR property that exposes the `DependencyProperty` object - something like this:

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentItemPropertyField =
    DependencyProperty.Register/RegisterAttached(...);

internal static DependencyProperty CurrentItemProperty
{
    get
    {
        return CurrentItemPropertyField;
    }
}
```

This allows tools such as Blend to discover the properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, it solved the question I had but now I'm getting new error. First this control I'm creating is recursive one (simply I'm trying to create treeview kind of user control). Now I'm getting this error from XAML "Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Xaml.PropertyPath' from the text ''". I will update xaml code in question.

Comment: Also I noticed that new error I mentioned is getting only on "Windows Runtime Component" projects. For normal Windows Store Apps project, your solution works perfectly.

Comment: That I don't know. WinRT components are a different beast than .NET libraries. They need to be consumable from C++ and JavaScript, so there are lots of additional requirements.

Comment: Okey. Thanks a lot for answer, saved my day. I removed "Windows Runtime Component" project and added user controls in separate folder in app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an automatic property setting the default value (from c# 5) like this:

```
public static DependencyProperty CurrentItemPropertyField { get; } = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata("{No Value}"));
```

Works also for UWP applications