# XAML RT Grid row height doesn't automatically resize when a textblock is rotated 90 degrees

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, winrt-xaml

I have a XAML RT Grid with 3 rows. I have a textblock in row 1 column 0 and I've rotated the text by 90 degrees. The Row's height has been set to auto but the row's height doesn't automatically adjust to the height of the rotated textblock. Can anybody help?

The code for the grid is below:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridDetails" Height="200"
      Margin="2"          
      Background="Yellow">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition  />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="1">
        <Run Text="Header" />
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
               Margin="0"                   
               RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"  >
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform Rotation="-90" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <Run Text="Sample Text" />
    </TextBlock>        
</Grid>
```

This is a window 8 store app using XAML RT and c#.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is expected with a RenderTransform, which affects only rendering and not layout.

This link may help:
http://igrali.com/2012/09/17/layout-transform-in-windows-8-winrt-xaml/

Comment: Hi Patrick, Have you tried this code? When I copy and use this code I receive a COMException Error. Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component. Any ideas what to do?

Comment: That error message isn't very helpful :(.  Not sure where your code is going wrong, I would need to see the stack and the code you tried.  I tried following this blog post and it worked for me.  I just needed to make the LayoutTransformer DependencyProperty internal (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15061659/cant-create-dependency-property-in-a-usercontrol-in-a-windows-runtime-component).  Here's the source with a sample app using the LayoutTransformer: https://github.com/finnigantime/Samples/tree/master/examples/Win8Xaml/LayoutTransformerWinRTPort

Comment: I get the COMException error in the designer (in Visual Studio), but not when running it. Also, Blend doesn't work with it. So I think there is a design time problem (though I have no idea what it is yet).

Comment: @Gordon I've seen instability in the designer before for XAML that runs fine, so I'm not surprised to hear that. However, I'm able to load MainPage.xaml from the test app in VS Pro 2012 and Blend 2012. If you get a reliable designer crash, consider reporting to the VS team with your version info.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickFinnigan How do I make a report like that? I'm happy to send those sorts of things back!

Comment: Hey Gordon, I think there are web portals such as UserVoice but looks like the easiest way is from VS go to Help > Feedback > Report a Bug (VS 2013) or Help > Report a Bug (VS 2012).

Answer (score 0):

You must use a LayoutTransform rather than a RenderTransform.

See MSDN for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750596.aspx#exampleRotateAnElement45degSection

Comment: LayoutTransform isn't there in RT XAML

Comment: Actually, this answer did help me with a similar non-RT issue. I was using render transform instead of layout transform :)